# iOS Setting Bundle vs InAppSettingsKit

Tags: ios, datepicker, application-settings, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

My iPhone app has few settings that depends on user's desire to change and it contains a Date Picker (Time Picker).
Is it possible to have Date Picker (Time Picker specifically) in setting bundle? According to the apple Documentation there are only a few type of elements that we can have in setting bundle. I was wondering if anybody had the same problem before? I already knew the other option for setting which is "InAppSettingsKit" but don't want to have this kind of setting inside of the app but in setting Bundle.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The schema for Settings bundles doesn't support date and time pickers. With InAppSettingsKit you can implement this by using a custom view controller.